# Ffmpeg stream at the same time to youtube and twitch

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, youtube, flv

I would like to stream my webcam to youtube and twitch in the same command line because the bandwidth to my camera is very narrow. I can stream either youtube or twitch using this command. How can ffmpeg stream at the same time to youtube and twitch ? Maybe I can use `tee` but I don't understand how to use with flv outputs.
 Thank you

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -thread_queue_size 1000k \
                -i rtsp://@192.168.100.1:1554/0/av0 \
                -framerate 12 -bufsize 1024k \
                -b:v 3500k -threads 4 -g 30\
                -q:v 1 -c:v libx264    -c:a aac -ab 44.1k -crf 25\
                -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xbxxx-xxx--xx-xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -thread_queue_size 1000k \
                -i rtsp://@192.168.100.1:1554/0/av0 \
                -framerate 12 -bufsize 1024k \
                -b:v 3500k -threads 4 -g 30\
                -q:v 1 -c:v libx264    -c:a aac -ab 44.1k -crf 25\
                -f tee -map 0:v -map 0:a "[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1/xxx-xxx-xxxx|[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://twitch_server/key "
```

Comment: `-q:v 1` is ignored by libx264, so you can remove it. `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive, so only use one or the other (generally use `-b:v` when streaming). You can let the encoder automatically choose the optimal number of threads if you remove `-threads`. `-framerate` is not an output option and is ignored. If you want to change the frame rate, which you probably don't need to, then use `-r` instead. Since you are using `-bufsize` you should also add `-maxrate`.